# Entity Framework Core updating specific entity property only when using a Generic Repository

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Hello is there a way that I could only update a specific field on my Entity when using a Generic Repository? Say:

EntityName

- Property1
- Property2

I only want to update the Property2, but with my Generic Repository implementation it is accepting only the whole Entity as parameter so when I execute the Update and SaveChanges the whole Entity is affected instead of only the Property2.

Comment: Just update property of the class returned by `DbContext` and don't call `Update` explicitly, `SaveChanges` will detect changes automatically. It should be tracked entity (without AsNoTtacking)

Answer (score 0):

@SvyatoslavDanyliv's comment will solution without AsNoTracking. With using AsNoTracking;

Modify your repository method like below;

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] projectionProperties)
{
    var dbEntry = _dbContext.Entry(entity);

    foreach (var includeProperty in projectionProperties)
        dbEntry.Property(includeProperty).IsModified = true;

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Usage;

```
await _someRepository.UpdateAsync(someEntity, p => p.SomeProperty);
```